# How can I traverse a panda dataframe using apply and also access the next value?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
x = {'depth':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],"Component":["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]}
y = {'depth':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],"Component":
["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"] ,"parent":["None","None","B","B","B","E","E","E","E"]}

x = pd.DataFrame(x)
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
```

So what I have is `x` and I want to create `y`, the difference between x and y is that there is a parent component for each depth so  for index: 1, is the parent of all rows from index: 2-4. Any idea on how I should proceed?

edit: so the .1 and .1.1 is just sample data( just to make it easier to visualize) but in my real data there is no correlation between each cell as simple as .1 or .1.1. Any work around for that?

Answer (score 2):

Let us do with `split` with `np.where`

```
s = x.Component.str.rsplit('.',n=1)
x['parent'] = np.where(s.str.len()>1,s.str[0],np.nan)
x
Out[566]: 
   depth Component parent
0      1         A    NaN
1      1         B    NaN
2      2       B.1      B
3      2       B.2      B
4      2       B.3      B
5      3     B.3.1    B.3
6      3     B.3.2    B.3
7      3     B.3.3    B.3
8      3     B.3.4    B.3
```

Comment: Could you try the same with the changed  data?

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.extract`.

```
x['parent'] = x['Component'].str.extract(r'(.*)\.')
```

Since '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible so the expression match until the last `.`. What is returned by `extract` is all text between `( )`

```
>>> x
   depth Component parent
0      1         A    NaN
1      1         B    NaN
2      2       B.1      B
3      2       B.2      B
4      2       B.3      B
5      3     B.3.1    B.3
6      3     B.3.2    B.3
7      3     B.3.3    B.3
8      3     B.3.4    B.3
```

---

**Old answer**
Use `str` accessor:

```
x['parent'] = x['Component'].str.split('.') \
                            .str[:-1] \
                            .str.join('.') \
                            .replace('', pd.NA)
```

```
>>> x
   depth Component parent
0      1         A   <NA>
1      1         B   <NA>
2      2       B.1      B
3      2       B.2      B
4      2       B.3      B
5      3     B.3.1    B.3
6      3     B.3.2    B.3
7      3     B.3.3    B.3
8      3     B.3.4    B.3
```

Comment: could you take a look at my edit above, please?

Comment: What is the problem? You have a separator between each component, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a working solution( that I came up with) if you guys think there is a easier way to do this, then please let me know

```
df = data
depth_lst = dict()
for row in df.head(200).iterrows():
    depth = row[1]["Depth"]
    if (depth not in depth_lst):
        depth_lst[int(depth)] = row[1]["Component"]
    else:
        depth_lst[int(depth)] = row[1]["Component"]
    if (depth == 1):
        row[1]["Parent Compoenet"] = "NA"
    else:
        row[1]["Parent Compoenet"] = depth_lst[depth - 1]

display(df.head(200))
```